# Timezone in Craft different from timezone in plugin

Tags: plugin-development

In `general.php` I've set `'timezone' => 'Europe/Oslo'`.

When saving entries through the CP they are saved with the correct time. Also, `date_default_timezone_get()` from my plugin returns `Europe/Oslo`.

However when I save something via the plugin, e.g.

```
$something = new Something();
...
$something->save();
```

the `dateCreated` field saves with the wrong time. In my case; 2 hours earlier than the `Europe/Oslo` time.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which plugin are you referring to? Something public, or something you wrote yourself?

Comment: I wrote it myself